# Purpose of "virtual" RedirectUri in Open ID Connect options

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, identityserver3, katana

In the IdentityServer test host, the RedirectUri for Azure AD is configured as a "virtual" URI, e.g. `RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44333/core/aadcb"` - virtual in the sense that there isn't really anything at `/aadcb`. This kind of setup also seems to be done in many of the Azure AD samples independent of Identity Server.

In the login flow for IdentityServer using Azure AD, Azure AD calls back to that virtual URI and then gets redirected to `/callback`. Where does this redirection occur? What is the purpose of doing it that way?

I have been troubleshooting an issue where we sometimes get a 404 at our virtual URL, and it seems like we can just use `/callback` directly. We only have the one external provider now, but that could change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple middlewares of the same type (e.g. multiple OpenID Connect or WS-Federation) - each of them need a unique callback path. Otherwise they would step on each other's toes with potentially different settings like key material.

The middleware then handles this "virtual" URL.